# Tup dependencies from the root directory?

Tags: tup

I've tried to create a rule similar to the minimal example:

```
: ../library/something local |> !compile |> ./something_else
```

This works, but I would like to write something like:

```
: $(PROJ_ROOT)/library/something local |> !compile |> ./something_else
```

Where the PROJ_ROOT variable is the same, even if I add folder depth.
Does tup support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the root directory to every subdirectory using
`include_rules`

In your top-level Tupfile you specify `TOP = $(TUP_CWD)`
In any child you write `include_rules`. You can now access `$(TOP)`
to get the relative path, which consists of `../../`, etc.